# How do I prove these properties on similar triangles (Euclidian Geometry)?

Tags: geometry

[image]

The author didn't give any hint. It just stated the theorem on similarity of triangles which I perfectly understood but found hard to apply to these problems.

Any hint ?

Comment: What is your definition of similarity?

Comment: What does $\;\hat{ABC}\;$ mean? The angle $\;\angle ABC\;$ ?

Comment: Two triangles are similar if their corresponding sides are proportional.

Comment: And yes, that's an angle.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{[ADE]}{[ABC]}=\underbrace{\frac{[ABE]}{[ABC]}}_{\frac{AE}{AC}}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{[ADE]}{[ABE]}}_{\frac{AD}{AB}}.$$

Comment: I agree but how do you prove that [ABE]/[ABC] is equal to AE/AC. I knew I had to find (AE*AD)/(AC*AB) but the important thing is to prove it.

Comment: @user3061105: if two triangles have the same height and the ratio of their bases is $k$, the ratio of the areas is $k$, too.

Comment: Please just tell me how to find the area of ABE and ABC

Comment: You just need the ratio of the areas. Just told you.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I got to work it out again. It's not obvious to me.

Comment: Do you have any hint for the first problem on similarity ?

Comment: @user3061105: again, break the problem in finding some areas ratios, where these areas belong to triangles with the same height and different bases, or the same base but different heights.